# Express JS Jade Engine If statement nested in For loop

Tags: template-engine, pug, express

I can't seem to find a solution to this.

I'm trying to nest a if statement inside a for loop in Jade engine (using express js).

The base code is shown below:

```
 form
    select
       for obj, i in phoneModel
          option(value='#{i}') #{obj.phone_model}
```

What I would like to do is to have a IF statement inside the for loop to check to see if a varaible "deviceIndex" is a certain value.  Eg.  If deviceIndex == i, then do something, else do some other thing.

I have tried the code below:

```
 form
    select
       for obj, i in phoneModel
          - if(phoneIndex == #{i})
             option(value='#{i}') #{obj.phone_model}
          - else
             option(value='#{i}' selected='selected') #{obj.phone_model}
```

It gives the "expect indent, but got newline" error.  I expect it is my placement of the if statement inside the for loop; however, I have tried just about every combination of tabs and spaces as well as putting the "option(val..." line inside a bracket on the same line as the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's with the typeof around a boolean? And shouldn't the phone with `phoneIndex == i` be the one selected? Also, the point of Jade is to have much cleaner code. Tell me if this works:

```
form
  select
    for obj, i in phoneModel  
      option(value=i, selected=phoneIndex==i)= obj.phone_model
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help.  This works great!

As for the typeof, that was a failed experiment I was trying when I was trying to figure out the answer by myself and accidentally copied.(Edited post to reflect this, thanks again for the help.)